# How do I create a 3" deep hole, 3/8" diameter, in granite?

Tags: repair

Does anybody have recommendations for the best method of creating a 3/8" diameter hole, 3" deep, in granite?

Comment: Masonry bit and a drill press will do it. It's best to drill underwater, so heat buildup does not fracture your granite. If You can't submerge, go slow, with frequent breaks, and once you've got a hole, add water to it periodically, so it can boil off, and cool the rock.

Comment: Need a hammer drill and a quality masonry bit. Drilling through granite is not a challenge at all. Stay away from cheapo bits with very thin tungsten carbide blades. Go slowly, withdraw often. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?   It says it's 4 inches overall length.

[https://www.amazon.com/Concrete-Beginners-Drilling-Shipping-Guarantee/dp/B01CUDK6LW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1497140514&sr=8-1&keywords=Drillglaas](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CUDK6LW)

Comment: Should, but overkill on the price. Masonry bits are good enough.